# How to create a popup window to select a file in a local directory?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file

I want to create a popup window that shows me all the files in a certain directory like ex a /functions directory. I want to be able to click a file in that directory, click ok, and store it's info in variables (not upload it), How would I do this?

I've tried using a form as:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But with that I can't specify a directory to open specificlly, I have to manually navigate to that directory.

I've tried using window.open()

```
window.open("file:///" + "home/user/Desktop/demo/functions");
```

I've tried using an onclick link mechanism:

```
<a onclick="file:///+ "home/user/Desktop/demo/functions"">Open folder</a>
```

None of these seem to work, any ways I could approach this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, because of the security. I really don't want that some website will get to specific folder in my computer.

Comment: I have to do this for an assignment, so I'm literally hopeless at this point.

Comment: Could I somehow do window.open, print all the files in the directory on there, be able to click those files somehow and click 'ok' ?

Comment: You can't do this without having server code read a directory. File access is blocked in browser for obvious security reasons. You could install node.js and use it as server to read directory

Comment: I'm not sure it will help but You can read [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) but: `In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec is not being considered by other browsers. For now, the API is Chrome-specific and it's unlikely to be implemented by other browsers and is no longer being standardized with the W3C.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, file handling gets a bit messy. The only way to grab the contents of a folder from JavaScript would be to connect to a server and have a serverside code  in a different language relay the folder information back to JavaScript.

The only way I can think that we could be able to *fake* this result is by placing an `index.html` file inside of the target directory. This `index.html` file would then have the names of all the files in the folder within it. However, they would have to be manually plugged into the HTML file. (if you know how to use PHP, it can scan a directory and push the contents to the HTML file)

When a web browser has to navigate to a folder, it asks the server for an `index` file (usually this will be an HTML or PHP file). This index would then have the contents of the folder inside of it.

If the folder is indeed on the local computer, however, there is one final way we can do this...

If the page navigates to a folder using a `window.location` of something akin to `file:///C://Users/USERNAME/Desktop/My%20Folder/`, chrome (or whatever browser you are using) will navigate to the directory and display the contents of the directory. However, since you can't put JavaScript into this browser-generated index page, you won't be able to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="file">` is probably your best bet, but you can't set a default directory with it (at least not without some JavaScript voodoo, and even then there are security issues between the web and the local user).

I don't know why you would want to do that, anyway, since directory structures are going to be different between different users, and the specification of paths is different between different OS's.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this I will suggest you copy that picture in project/image folder after clicking the upload button.